# Возвратите True, если студенты учатся в заданных обстоятельствах

Tags: python

```py
def students_study(time: int, coffee_needed: bool) -> bool:
    """Если это вечернее и ночное время (между 18:00 и 24:00, включая конечные точки),то пить кофе не важно. Если это утро и время обеда (с 5 до 17 часов включительно), то пить кофе крайне важно. Между 1 и 4 (включая конечные точки) пить кофе нельзя.
    Пример: (19, False) -> True
    (1, True) -> False.
    """
    if 24 >= time >= 18 and coffee_needed == False:
        return True
    elif 17 >= time >= 5 and coffee_needed == True:
        return True
    elif 4 >= time >= 1 and coffee_needed == False:
        return True
```

При запуске теста

```py
print(students_study(19, False))
print(students_study(1, True))
```

Питон выдает ответ `True; None`. Тоесть алгоритм по какой-то причине не работает. Можете помочь разобраться с ошибкой? Может можно сократить алгоритм?

Comment: у вас нет кода на случай, если coffee_needed True

Comment: А можете помочь исправить код?

Comment: ну вы попробуйте сами подумать, что делать в этом случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут скорей надо нам самим алгоритмом поразмыслить.

Если я правильно понял, то для двух промежутков времени, переменная `coffee_needed` вообще не нужна:

1. С 18-24, пить кофе не важно
2. С 1-4, пить кофе нельзя, то есть при любом значении данной переменной возвращаем `False`

Если я правильно понял эти условия из вашего описания, то сначала проверям эти временные промежутки без участия переменной `coffee_needed`. А затем пишем условие для оставшегося временного промежутка

```py
def students_study(time_: int, coffee_needed: bool) -> bool:
    if 24 >= time_ >= 18:
        return True
    if 4 >= time_ >= 1:
        return False
    if  17 >= time_ >= 5:
        if coffee_needed:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Проверяем

```py
>>> print(students_study(19, False))
True
>>> print(students_study(1, True))
False
```

Переименовал переменную `time` в `time_`, поскольку есть одноименный модуль.

Если взглянуть детальнее, то можно сократить до вот такого кода

```py
def students_study(time_: int, coffee_needed: bool) -> bool:
    if 24 >= time_ >= 18:
        return True
    if  17 >= time_ >= 5 and coffee_needed:
        return True
    return False
```

Возвращать `True` только при необходимых условиях, если ни одно не попало и функция дошла до последней строки, то вернуть `False`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, уже думал, может отдельно выписать алгоритм для coffee needed, но видимо слишком запарился, что не додумался сам.

Comment: На здоровье, обратите внимание на эту тему [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)